# Shift operator usage in terms of classes

Tags: c++, bit-shift, bitcoin

I have this line of C++ code and don't know what the shift operator does:

```
vRecv >> locator >> hashStop
```

Identifiers are of the following types:

- vRecv: `CDataStream CNetMessage::vRecv`, instance of the CDataStream class and public attribute of CNetMessage class
- locator: `CBlockLocator locator`, instance of CBlockLocator struct
- hashStop: `uint256 hashStop`, instance of uint256 class

What is important for me to know, in this case?

Comment: Well, you need to refer to these classes documentation, how the operator is overloaded for their particular means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [BitCoin documentation](https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/index.html). `vRecv` is an instance of [`CDataStream`](https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/class_c_data_stream.html) which overloads the [operator>>](https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/class_c_data_stream.html#ac80cfc65569416f8c23e328edb4cadae) to read and unserialize data.

**Background**

To understand the expression, [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) and [associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) of operators are important. In C++, the `>>` operator is [left-associative](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~cs240/misc/operators.html), which means you can rewrite your expression

```
(vRecv >> locator) >> hashStop;

// Or in terms of actual function calls...
( vRecv.operator>>(locator) ).operator>>(hashStop);
```

**Interpretation**

Looking at the [code for the operator>>](https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/streams_8h_source.html#l00287) you see that the method takes an argument of type `T` and returns a reference to itself. In your particular case, the argument is an instance of [CBlockLocator](https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/block_8h_source.html#l00137) (a [STL vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of [uint256](https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/uint256_8h_source.html#l00112) elements). Notice that the `operator>>` calls [Unserialize](https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/serialize_8h_source.html#l00213) which effectively reads bytes from a stream.

Thus

```
(vRecv >> locator)
```

reads bytes from the `vRecv` stream into your `locator` object, returns the same stream meaning that next this is executed

```
vRecv >> hashStop
```

which advances the stream to read bytes into the `hashStop` object. So, long story short: *fill the `locator` and `hashStop` objects with bytes from the stream*.

Comment: Danke für die hilfreiche Antwort, Jens! here's a link to the line in the actual code: [main.cpp](https://dev.visucore.com/bitcoin/doxygen/main_8cpp_source.html#l04227). So this operator is kind of a custom operator for (un)serializing data and has nothing to do with the (bitwise) shift operator, right?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi: thanks for the link, I've detailed my answer.

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi: and you are correct, in this case `>>` is overloaded to read data from a stream. It is _not_ meant to be a bitwise shift operator. (In C++, `<<` and `>>` are often overloaded to read/write data from/to streams.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, one gets encouraged not to give up with such answers as yours!

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi: you're welcome. As for streams in C++, take a look at [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html) tutorial. The [C++ STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) provides various streams for [input](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/), [output](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/), or over [strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/).

Comment: Actually found exactly same link myself that's why deleted my question :D thanks though!!!